# Receiving urllib error with Shopify scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, shopify

I'm building this Shopify scraper to scraper the shop properties like address, phone, email, etc. and I'm receiving a urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: not found. The CSV is being created with the header but not scraping any of the information. Why isn't the address being scraped?

```
import csv
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

base_url = sys.argv[1]
url = base_url + '/shopprops.json'

def get_page(page):
    data = urlopen(url + '?page={}'.format(page)).read()
    shopprops = json.loads(data)['shopprops']
    return shopprops
  
with open('shopprops.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Address1'])
    page = 1
    shop = get_page(page)
    while shopprops:
        for shop in shopprops:
            address1 = shop['address1']
            row = [address1]
            writer.writerow(row)
        page += 1
        shopprops = get_page(page)
```

It looks like the issue's with:

```
data = urlopen(url + '?page={}'.format(page)).read()
```

and:

```
shopprops = get_page(page)
```

Comment: What's the base url you are using?

Comment: I got a Shopify product scraper working from this medium article:
https://medium.com/@lagenar/how-to-create-a-scraper-for-shopify-a98b6fb2cacb
Idk what the base URL but I only changed the names around and used the shop properties instead of product properties

Answer (score 0):

That article is crappy for a few reasons, which might help you to move on. First off, you can't scrape a shop like that guy says just asking for products.json. You get a really small payload of a few products at best, with no really interesting information exposed. Shopify is wise to that.

So before you invest too much effort in your scraper, you might want to re-think what you're doing, and instead, maybe try a different approach than this one.

Comment: This is what I used for the products. https://github.com/helloiamelliot/shopify-python-scraping-tool. But I'm trying to scrape the shop properties now and don't understand why it's not scraping the properties

Comment: Shouldn't everything here be freely accessible?
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/store-properties/shop

Comment: Absolutely NOT. Resources are locked behind authorization tokens. So you cannot scrape Shopify except for the most trivial of data.